# Functions that help to understand json(dict) structure

Tags: python

I haven't found is there a way to do this.
Let's say I recieve a JSON object like this:

```
{'1_data':{'4_data':[{'5_data':'hooray'}, {'3_data':'hooray2'}], '2_data':[]}}
```

It's hard to instantly say, how should I get value from **3_data key**: `data['1_data']['4_data'][1]['3_data']`

I know about `pprint`, it helps to understand structure a bit.
But sometimes data is huge, and it takes time

Are there any methods that may help me with that?

Comment: what if the key is present in several sub-dictionaries / while traversing the dicts? where to stop? You'd like to flatten your dict maybe.

Comment: how do you get the json? Is it a file? Then e.g. a tool like [jk](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) might good to get a first understanding of the file

Comment: you have Python so use it and write some function to find key in structure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are a family of recursive generators that can be used to search through an object composed of dicts and lists. `find_key` yields a tuple containing a list of the dictionary keys and list indices that lead to the key that you pass in; the tuple also contains the value associated with that key. Because it's a generator it will find all matching keys if the object contains multiple matching keys, if desired.

```
def find_key(obj, key):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        yield from iter_dict(obj, key, [])
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        yield from iter_list(obj, key, [])

def iter_dict(d, key, indices):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == key:
            yield indices + [k], v
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from iter_dict(v, key, indices + [k])
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            yield from iter_list(v, key, indices + [k])

def iter_list(seq, key, indices):
    for k, v in enumerate(seq):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from iter_dict(v, key, indices + [k])
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            yield from iter_list(v, key, indices + [k])

# test

data = {
    '1_data': {
        '4_data': [
            {'5_data': 'hooray'},
            {'3_data': 'hooray2'}
        ], 
        '2_data': []
    }
}

for t in find_key(data, '3_data'):
    print(t)
```

**output**

```
(['1_data', '4_data', 1, '3_data'], 'hooray2')
```

---

To get a single key list you can pass `find_key` to the `next` function. And if you want to use a key list to fetch the associated value you can use a simple `for` loop.

```
seq, val = next(find_key(data, '3_data'))
print('seq:', seq, 'val:', val)

obj = data
for k in seq:
    obj = obj[k]
print('obj:', obj, obj == val)
```

**output**

```
seq: ['1_data', '4_data', 1, '3_data'] val: hooray2
obj: hooray2 True
```

If the key may be missing, then give `next` an appropriate default tuple. Eg:

```
seq, val = next(find_key(data, '6_data'), ([], None))
print('seq:', seq, 'val:', val)
if seq:
    obj = data
    for k in seq:
        obj = obj[k]
    print('obj:', obj, obj == val)
```

**output**

```
seq: [] val: None
```

---

Note that this code is for Python 3. To run it on Python 2 you need to replace all the `yield from` statements, eg replace

```
yield from iter_dict(obj, key, [])
```

with

```
for u in iter_dict(obj, key, []):
    yield u
```

---

#### How it works

To understand how this code works you need to be familiar with [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) and with Python [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators). You may also find this page helpful: [Understanding Generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1756096/4014959); there are also various Python generators tutorials available online.

The Python object returned by `json.load` or `json.loads` is generally a dict, but it can also be a list. We pass that object to the `find_key` generator as the `obj` arg, along with the `key` string that we want to locate. `find_key` then calls either `iter_dict` or `iter_list`, as appropriate, passing them the object, the key, and an empty list `indices`, which is used to collect the dict keys and list indices that lead to the key we want.

`iter_dict` iterates over each (k, v) pair at the top level of its `d` dict arg. If `k` matches the key we're looking for then the current `indices` list is yielded with `k` appended to it, along with the associated value. Because `iter_dict` is recursive the yielded (indices list, value) pairs get passed up to the previous level of recursion, eventually making their way up to `find_key` and then to the code that called `find_key`. Note that this is the "base case" of our recursion: it's the part of the code that determines whether this recursion path leads to the key we want. If a recursion path never finds a key matching the key we're looking for then that recursion path won't add anything to `indices` and it will terminate without yielding anything.

If the current `v` is a dict, then we need to examine all the (key, value) pairs it contains. We do that by making a recursive call to `iter_dict`, passing that `v` is its starting object and the current `indices` list. If the current `v` is a list we instead call `iter_list`, passing it the same args.

`iter_list` works similarly to `iter_dict` except that a list doesn't have any keys, it only contains values, so we don't perform the `k == key` test, we just recurse into any dicts or lists that the original list contains.

The end result of this process is that when we iterate over `find_key` we get pairs of (indices, value) where each `indices` list is the sequence of dict keys and list indices that succesfully terminate in a dict item with our desired key, and `value` is the value associated with that particular key.

If you'd like to see some other examples of this code in use please see [how to modify the key of a nested Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46701223/4014959) and [How can I select deeply nested key:values from dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47075972/4014959).

Also take  look at my new, more streamlined [`show_indices`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52414034/4014959) function.

Comment: Thank you for the recursion function.I way able to execute find_key() but I get "TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly" in the yield from line in iter_dict(), trying to print the dictionary. Any solution?

Comment: @Kaleab I need to see the code (with some data) that's causing the problem. So add it to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037281/how-can-i-select-deeply-nested-keyvalues-from-dictionary-in-python) and I'll take a look at it shortly.

Comment: Too bad I can't give you more than one up-vote. That was an excellent explanation and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you @ColinWu

Comment: I second @Colin... this was great!