# Retreive JSON Keys In Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, typeerror

My goal is to iterate through ***every*** element in `classes` and add the value of `class` in `classes` into a new list.

**JSON Structure:**

```
{
    "images": [
      {
        "classifiers": [
          {
            "classes": [
              {
                "class": "street",
                "score": 0.846
              },
              {
                "class": "road",
                "score": 0.85
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
}
```

In the above JSON example, the new list should contain:

```
{'street','road'}
```

I tried to iterate over `json_data['images'][0]['classifiers']['classes']` and for each one `list.append()` the value of `class`.

```
list = list()
def func(json_data):
    for item in json_data['images'][0]['classifiers']['classes']:
        list.append(item['class'])
    return(list)
```

I am receiving a `TypeError` which is:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What I am getting from this `TypeError` is that it attempts to add a string to the list but `list.append()` does not accept a string as a paramet. I need to somehow convert the string into something else.

My question is what should I convert the string into so that `list.append()` will accept it as a parameter?

Comment: Thanks for showing us your input & expected output. Now show us the code you've written to do this, and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: I keeep getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str and using that error and trying things on StackOverflow to fix that error are not working.

Comment: Please include the full traceback as an edit too.

Comment: Thanks for adding some code. "classifiers" is a list, so you need to use a numeric index to get at its contents, just like you did with "images".

Comment: `classifiers` and `classes` are also lists. `json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]['classes']:`

Comment: What code do I need to get this to work. I tried a numeric index and got the same error. Can you please post an answer to the question and I will also mark it as correct if it is.

Comment: The code that  roganjosh just showed you will get the list of dicts in "classes".

Comment: It is working but it is returning ['street','road','yellow color','green color'] not {'street','road','yellow color','green color'}... How can I make it not do that? And does someone want to post it as an answer? @PM2Ring

Comment: `return set(lst)` I think. If that is what you expect I'll have a go at writing an answer on my phone - always fun - so you can close this.

Comment: Tracing through JSON to find the correct sequence of dict keys and  list indices can be painful. It can help a bit if you do `json.dumps(json_data, indent=4)`. Or you can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41778581/4014959) I wrote a few months ago.

Comment: What does this mean?  Doing  `if ['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]["classes"] not in json_data:` Gives me
`TypeError: string indices must be integers` @PM2Ring  @roganjosh

Comment: `['images']` is a list containing a single string. `['images'][0]` gets the first item in that list, which is the string `'images'`. So `['images'][0]['classifiers']` is the same as `'images'['classifiers']`, and Python is  telling you that it doesn't make sense because string indices must be integers. You could do (for example) `'images'[3]`, that would give you the `'g'` in  `'images'`. I _suspect_ you were really wanting to do `if "classes" not in json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]:`

Comment: Yes but when I do that it says list index out of range

Comment: @PM2Ring Here is the other question more explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313266/if-json-key-exists-else

Comment: @PM2Ring  I just rewrote the question. I hope it is better! If you think it is and you want to could you please upvote it! Thanks! I already figured it out but wanted to make it better in case someone else needs help!

Comment: @roganjosh Please look at the above comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that `classifiers` is also a list, so you need an additional index to get at `classes`. This will work:

```
for item in json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]['classes']:
```

Second, you want the result as a set not a list, so you can do: `return set(lst)`. Note that sets are unordered, so don't expect the ordering of items to match that of the list.

Comment: How do I make it ordered?

Comment: Why do you need it to be both a set and ordered before we go down that route?

Comment: It actully does not need to be a set. It can be a list

Comment: I just need it to have the {}

Comment: What does this mean?  Doing  `if ['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]["classes"] not in json_data:` Gives me
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: @Brendan `['street','road','yellow color','green color']` is a list of strings, `{'street','road','yellow color','green color'}` is a set of strings. Python sets don't maintain the order of their items. So if you "just need it to have the {}" then you need a set. Note that JSON doesn't support sets.

Comment: Here is the other question more explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313266/if-json-key-exists-else