# Conditional statement to check if a JSON key is null with Python 3

Tags: python, json, if-statement, conditional-statements

This has been updated to clarify the question so it can better help others in the future.

---

I am attempting to use an if statement to test if the key `classes` exists in a JSON structure using Python. to check if a key exists in a JSON structure using Python. I am able to get the key but need help finding out what the condition should be to check if it exists.

I successfully was able to return the value of the key `class` when it is exsits in the JSON structure using the following code:

```
#Parameter: json_data - The JSON structure it is checking
def parse_classes(json_data):
    lst = list()
    if('classes' is in json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]): #This doesn't work
        for item in json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]['classes']: 
            lst.append(item['class'])
    else:
        lst = None

    return(lst)
```

---

**Example `json_data`:**

```
{"images": ["classifiers": ["classes": ["class": "street"]]]}
```

---

My issue seems to be on line 4 and the issue seems to be that the conditional statement is incorrect. What do I need to change about the if-statement to make it work correctly?

Comment: `for item in json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]['classes']`: shouldn't it be `for item in classes` ?

Comment: This is a follow-up question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310791/retrieve-multiple-json-items-python?noredirect=1#comment77589110_45310791

Comment: you need to check  `len(json_data['images'])` , then  `len(json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'])`

Comment: you're screenshot doesn't match the code you posted (quotes vs no quotes for classes). I first edited it but cmd answer made me rollback.

Comment: It doesn't work, so how can it work with or without quotes?

Comment: Although I figured it out, I just updated my question in case someone in the future needs help. If you think it is better and improved and you want to, would you mind removing your down vote and if you want to upvote do that too please. Thanks a lot! @AlanLeuthard

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ^

Comment: @PM2Ring Please look at two comments above this one.

Comment: @PRMoureu Please look three comments above this one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean `if` instead of `for`:

```
def parse_classes(json_data):
    lst = set()
    if 'classes' in json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]:
        for item in json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]['classes']:
            lst.add(item['class'])
    else:
        print("")
    return lst
```

or defensively

```
def parse_classes(json_data):
    lst = set()
    if (json_data.get('images')
            and json_data['images'][0].get('classifiers')
            and json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'][0].get('classes')):
        for item in json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'][0].get('classes', []):
            lst.add(item['class'])
    return lst if lst else None
```

if you want all `class` in all `classifiers` in all `images`

```
def parse_classes(json_data):
    lst = set()
    for image in json_data.get('images', []):
        for classifier in image.get('classifiers', []):
            for item in classifier.get('classes', []):
                lst.add(item['class'])
    return lst if lst else None
```

Comment: Still says `IndexError: List index out of range`

Comment: It works for the json data you have given.  Do you have the data for when this fails?

Comment: `json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'][0]` must be empty in one of the sub-lists. cannot reproduce

Comment: @cmd I added the code. With your second thing it still says list index out of range.

Comment: will need to see full error and/or data it errors on.

Comment: `def parse_classes(json_data):
    lst = set()
    if json_data.get('images') and json_data['images'][0].get('classifiers'):
        for item in json_data['images'][0]['classifiers'][0].get('classes', []):
            lst.add(item['class'])
    else:
        lst = None
    return lst`

Comment: that works it is your second one but in the else statement replace print with lst=None

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Brendan updated to return None instead of empty set

Comment: @Brendan as a note: lists usually imply there can be more then one element, you may want to iterate over more then just the `[0]`th element.