# Python: Loop Nested JSON with unknown depth

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON response coming back which does a general structure, however, they can be N number of nested results ('queues').  I'm trying to understand how I can loop through all of the nested results which could go extremely deep.  I included a link to trinket with the long JSON response.  Basically, there are N number of leaf queues that can have no limit, so how can i keep looping deeper?  Right now i get stuck as 2 levels down.

```
import json

with open('sample_response.json') as data_file:    
    theJSON = json.load(data_file)

queuesJson = theJSON['scheduler']['schedulerInfo']['queues']['queue']

def get_leaf_queue_info (childQueue):
    for queue in childQueue:
        print ('nested +' + queue.get('queueName'))

for queue in queuesJson:
    print (queue.get('queueName'))
    if (len(queue['queues']['queue']) > 1):
        get_leaf_queue_info(queue['queues']['queue'])
```

[Link to Code and Sample JSON Response I'm parsing](https://trinket.io/python/1a3a4423f6)

Comment: To handle arbitrarily deep nesting you need to use recursion. Take a look at my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41778581/4014959), you can probably adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a nested structure - effectively a tree, consisting of nodes that can have child nodes and your task is to:

1. traverse the tree from the root,
2. do some work for each node,
3. traverse each child node.

This is the most classic case for recursion.

---

In generic terms we cold define a recursive function `traverse()` like so:

```
def traverse(node):
    do_work(node)
    for child in children_of(node):
        traverse(child)
```

This would visit every node and do some work on it. Since it is so generic, it would work on *any* tree, assuming that `do_work()` and `children_of()` are 
 defined.

---

In order to remove that implicit dependency and make the `traverse()` function truly generic, let's make it explicit:

```
def traverse(node, do_work, children_of):
    do_work(node)
    for child in children_of(node):
        traverse(child)
```

---

Now for your case, a function that gets the children for any node would look like this:

```
def sub_queues(queue):
    return queue.get('queues', {}).get('queue', [])
```

And a function that does some work could look like this:

```
def print_name(queue):
    print(queue.get('queueName'))
```

And we could call it like this:

```
root = data['scheduler']['schedulerInfo']
traverse(root, print_name, sub_queues)
```

---

A `traverse()` function that informs the worker of the current recursion depth (useful if you want to print something with indentation, for example) and cancels the recursion when the worker function returns `False` could look like this:

```
def traverse(node, do_work, children_of):
    continue_working = True

    def work(node, depth=0):
        if continue_working:
            result = do_work(node, depth=depth)
            if continue_working and result == False:
                continue_working = False
                return
            for child in children_of(node):
                work(child, depth + 1)

    work(node)
```